# loop through the two vectors and print using R

Tags: r, loops

lets say I have two vectors:

```
vector1=c("name1","name2","name3")
vector2=c("#DAAD03","#301EE1","#5BD066")
```

I would like to loop through the two vectors and print the following lines:

```
vector2[1] <- "#DAAD03" > name1
vector2[2] <- "#301EE1" > name2
vector2[3] <- "#5BD066" > name3
```

I tried:

```
for (i in vectors1){
  number=c(1)
  for (j in vectors2{
    print ("vectors2[",number,"] <- ",j, ">", i )
    number = number+1
  }
}
```

but it does not work. 
thanks for your help

I get the following error:

```
> for (i in vectors1){
+   number=c(1)
+   for (j in vectors2{
Erreur : '{' inattendu(e) in:
"  number=c(1)
  for (j in vectors2{"
>     print ("vectors2[",number,"] <- ",j, ">", i )
Error in print.default("vectors2[", number, "] <- ", j, ">", i) : 
  objet 'j' introuvable
>     number = number+1
>   }
Erreur : '}' inattendu(e) in "  }"
> }
Erreur : '}' inattendu(e) in "}"
>
```

Comment: correct the function first. } is missing for both the loops and also post the error you are getting. also use the same variable name through out the code, "vector" or "vectors"

Comment: You mean this? `paste0(vector2, ' > ', vector1)`

Comment: Well I have to include the `vectors2[number]` in the print as well which changes over i and j.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i in 1:length(vector1)){
  cat(paste0("vector2[",i,"] <- ","'",vector2[i],"'"," > ", vector1[i]))
}

 vector2[1] <- '#DAAD03' > name1
 vector2[2] <- '#301EE1' > name2
 vector2[3] <- '#5BD066' > name3
```

watch out for redundant loops, if you have big matrices/vectors they will take forever to run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
    for(i in 1:length(vector1)){
    print(paste(vector2[i],">",vector1[i]))}
```

Output:

```
    [1] "#DAAD03 > name1"
    [1] "#301EE1 > name2"
    [1] "#5BD066 > name3"
```

Do note that you've couple of missing brackets too, and you don't have to use multiple loops if both vectors are of same length.